# Codekit + Neat compiling error

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat, codekit

I'm new to Neat/Bourbon and trying to setup using Codekit so that I can begin building some awesome grids!

I have installed Neat using the built in Codekit version by inserting `@import "neat";` into my main SCSS file. It appears that this is working as I see a small snippet of code inserted into my CSS file, which I understand is the only CSS Neat inserts by default. This code is:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit; }
```

So, all appears to be importing correctly, however when trying to use any mixing form the Neat documentation I'm getting the following error from Codekit, hence preventing the compiler to complete:

Libsass: Error: no mixin named grid-column

Backtrace:
        Users/petedungey/Desktop/Dropbox/Oak/Internal/Flywheel Local Sites/woocommerce-blueprint-site/app/public/wp-content/themes/oak_starter_theme/sass/layout/_grid.scss:14
        on line 14 of Users/petedungey/Desktop/Dropbox/Oak/Internal/Flywheel Local Sites/woocommerce-blueprint-site/app/public/wp-content/themes/oak_starter_theme/sass/layout/_grid.scss

@include grid-column(3);
-----------^

Can anybody assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through [CodeKit’s Updates page](https://codekitapp.com/updates/), it seems that it still packages Neat 1.7.2. However, the `grid-column` mixin is from Neat 2.0.

You can view documentation for 1.7.2 here: http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/1.7.2/

Comment: Ah, thanks Tyson, well spotted. Shouldn't assume Codekit has the latest versions!

Comment: v3.0.8 of Codekit has _just_ updated to version 2.0 of Neat ([see Codekit Updates](https://codekitapp.com/updates/)). If you update your version of Codekit to the latest version and you compile your SCSS it should use Neat 2.0 and you can start using the newer syntax.